# UIImageView rotation with anchor point as right end

Tags: ios, uiimageview, rotation, uiviewanimation

In my app i need to rotate a image between 0-90(deg)clockwise and vice-versa.for this first i am creating a imageview

```
self.needleImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,155, 15,150)];
self.needleImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1.0);// Shift the Needle center point to one of the end points of the needle image.
self.needleImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.needleImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Arrow.png"];
[self.view addSubview:self.needleImageView];
```

With this code the image is coming in vertical direction.to get image in horizontal direction I am applying CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);

```
self.needleImageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
```

After this to rotate the image i used following animation code
//to rotate from 0-90 with autoreverse, after completing the animation to keep image in original position i have written the code in completion

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.8f
                      delay: 0.0f
                    options: (UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse)
                 animations: ^{
                     self.needleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.needleImageView.transform,M_PI/2);
                 }
                 completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                     self.needleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.needleImageView.transform,-M_PI/2);
                 }];
```

When i ran this code the image is coming in horizontal position,once i clicked on the animation button to apply animation the image rotation is starting from 270 deg-0 deg and vice versa..after animation image is positioning at 270 deg (vertically)

I want the image to be rotate between 0-90 deg only.
Please run this code so you can understand my problem clearly
Any help please...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve the problem:

```
 self.needleImageView1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
 //now animation
```

Note if u have `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` then `no use` for `completion block`.

Comment: Hi Now iam keeping the line of code before animation    self.needleImageView1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
And also made completion as NULL.Now initially the image is positioning at 180 deg, the animation is starting from 90 deg to 180 deg and then 180 to 90 after animation image is positioning agin at 180 deg it is not working properly

Comment: Can u please share your mail id,So that u can review my code.